# Incorrect 'display' style attribute

Tags: javascript, css, display

I need to check the `display`style attribute for a given `div`. In the document below, both divs' `display` attribute is set through css (one to `none`, the other to `block`) and later through javascript when the button is clicked, but `div.style.display` is empty as long as it has not been set by script (hence I need two clicks on the buttons to get the correct values).

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mydiva").style.display;
  document.getElementById("mydiva").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mydivb").style.display;
  document.getElementById("mydivb").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
      #mydiva {
        display:block;
      }
      #mydivb {
        display:none;
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="b">See</button>
<p id="dispa">display</p>
<div id="mydiva">
  sample div a
</div>
<p id="dispb">display</p>
<div id="mydivb">
  sample div b
</div>
```

Note: in my project, reading of `display` is to happen in `window.onload`, not through button press, but results are the same.

Comment: why not just do it with css hover, active and focus?

Comment: Use `getComputedStyle()`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude That worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @CarolMcKay I need to know if a div is initially displayed or not, I don't see how your suggestion can help me with that... any details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `display` style using the function below

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dispa").innerHTML = getDisplayStyle("mydiva");
  document.getElementById("mydiva").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("dispb").innerHTML = getDisplayStyle("mydivb");
  document.getElementById("mydivb").style.display = "none";
}

function getDisplayStyle(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId)
  return element.currentStyle ? element.currentStyle.display :
    getComputedStyle(element, null).display;
}
```

```css
#mydiva {
  display: block;
}
#mydivb {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="b">See</button>
<p id="dispa">display</p>
<div id="mydiva">
  sample div a
</div>
<p id="dispb">display</p>
<div id="mydivb">
  sample div b
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="dispa">display</p>
<div id="mydiva" style="display:none;">
    sample div a
</div>
<p id="dispb">display</p>
<div id="mydivb">
    sample div b
</div>




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b").click(function(){
        $("#mydiva").toggle();
        $("#mydivb").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Is this what you trying to do?

Comment: Yep, but without jQuery (that's what the `$`stuff is about, right? I'm a total noob in javascript).